# Get pixels divergence of scaled element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example I have an element e.g. image with next css:

```
img{
width:400;
height:285;
transition: all .3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
img:hover{
transform: scale(1.04,1.04);
-ms-transform: scale(1.04,1.04);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.04,1.04);
}
```

On this image I have absolute banner that appears on image hover and  moves according to image offset position, thus on image scaling the offset of the image is changed and my banner get "zoomed" image offset instead of normal one. I'd like to calculate divergence in pixels in order to reduce this value from the absolute banner `left` and `top` css values.
I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526498/556526), but it seems to be not working properly.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you illustrate with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? Good explanation but would _clear the fog up_ a bit so to speak.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just want to center the image after hovering, right? Try using `transform-origin` - http://jsfiddle.net/gp4ugwxL/. But if you need the pixels difference, `scale` is nothing more that multiplication, just take `width` and `height` with JavaScript and multiply it by `1.04`.

Comment: @urbz I`ve the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xt6o2pa4/4/, however i can not simulate the problem that have in my case via jsfiddle. Just in some cases  the image is hovered and I have offset of hovered image not of the image in regular state, thus my banner is in the wrong offset after image hover